# How to make a child process exit abnormally after receiving SIGSEGV?

Tags: c, linux, process

I wrote a program to intentionally let the child process to trigger SIGSEGV. However, I want the child process to terminate abnormally. Right now I use exit() in the signal handler. But exit() call will always generate a normal termination. Which function should I use to achieve that? Another question is how can I let the parent process know that the child process terminates because of SIGSEGV?

```
extern char  etext, edata, end;
void handler() {
  pid_t pid;
  pid = getpid();

  char buf[100];
  snprintf(buf, 100, "child %d terminated by signal 11", (int)pid);
  psignal(SIGSEGV, buf);
  exit(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (signal(SIGSEGV, handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    perror("signal error");
  }

  printf("First address beyond:\n");
  printf("    program text segment(etext)      %10p\n", &etext);
  printf("    initialized data segment(edata)  %10p\n", &edata);
  printf("    uninitialized data segment (end) %10p\n", &end);

  if (fork() == 0) {
    printf("from Child before\n");
    etext = 'a';
    printf("from Child after\n");
  } else {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    if ((pid == waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) >= 0) {
      printf("Handler reaped child %d\n", (int)pid);
    }
    printf("child WIFEXITED = %d, WEXITSTATUS = %d\n", WIFEXITED(status), WEXITSTATUS(status));
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == -3) {
      printf("Capture the exit code\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is the _exit() function, which doesn't call the atexit() functions, but only terminates (absormaly) immidiately.

Comment: I get a whole bundle of errors from running your code through `cc sigsegv.c` (after saving it to `sigsegv.c`), with gcc 4.7.2. Can you please fix the code so that it compiles?

Comment: [`abort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/abort) or [`kill()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) if you want `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: I suppose you could reset the signal handler and then trigger a segmentation violation yourself? (For example by dereferencing the null pointer.) That will trigger a SIGSEGV and end the process, but of course the error will occur at some location *other than* that where the original error occured.

Comment: How do you define abnormal termination?

Answer (score 2):

1. To cause the child exit by a signal, unregister a handler, unblock the signal, and `raise` it.

   ```
   // unregister SIGSEGV handler
   signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);

   // unblock SIGSEGV
   sigset_t mask;
   sigemptyset (&mask);
   sigaddset (&mask, SIGSEGV);
   if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, &mask) < 0)
       perror ("Could not unblock");

   // raise SIGSEGV
   raise (SIGSEGV);
   ```

   You need to unblock if you are in a handler for that signal, for example. It is recommended to use `sigaction` instead of plain C standard `signal`, this is however not shown here.
2. To check in the parent process whether a child was terminated by a signal:

   ```
   if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
       printf("child killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. However, in step 1, I only need signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL); to achieve the purpose and I tested in the code. Why do I need to unblock SIGSEGV?

Comment: What does SIG_DFL handler do? Can I modify my own handler to do something similar?